# Dual Wielding mechanics in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

OK, so "*no lollygagging*", basically what i want to know is:

1. Do all "on hit effects", such as weapon perks and enchantments, come in play when you power attack and not only when you swing normally?
2. If they do, does the target then get separately affected by all 4 strikes from a duel power attack and the 2 from swinging "normally" with both your weapons at the same time? (it's done by pressing M1 and M2, not holding them down, at the same time)

Thank you, if you took time out of your awesome day to answer this question!!! :D

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Exchange. I editted your title to make it more relevent and easier for users to find. Hope you get an answer to your question!

Answer (score 2):

For you 1st question yes on hit effects occur during both normal and power attacks. As for your second question I believe that your target will be affected each time your weapon touches them so yes seperate effects will occur for each strike including "normal" swings with two weapons.

Answer (score 1):

> and the 2 from swinging "normally" with both your weapons at the same time?

A test: 1 iron dagger enchanted with fear, 1 iron dagger enchanted with soul drain.

I swung both weapons at the same time against a wolf.

- The first swing didn't kill it and it ran.
- The second swing (30 seconds later) killed it and the soul was drained.

Conclusion: both daggers had their effects applied both times.